# Which code will be handled first in Android?

Tags: java, android

I want to know which code will be handled first.

1.
`Intent` or `"ABC"`?

```
Intent i = new Intent("ABC");
```

2.
`getWindow()`, `requestFeature()` or `Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR`?

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
```

Thanks

I mean which code will be handled first in the memory or CPU. This is not an exam question in deed.

I am an absolute beginner.

So, in case 2,

Window>.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR>getWindow()>requestFeature()

Right? Thanks.

Comment: This feels like a exam question.

Comment: in both cases `ABC` and `Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR` are just flags to indicate what intent/feature you want, there is nothing to handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an exam question but I'm in the mood today and I feel like you should know this so here is a short explanation:

**Inside-out and left to right**

1) It's a no brainer, the instruction will create you a new instance using the parameters you pass. In your case is easier because it needs a `String` but imagine you have

```
Car car = new Car(engine);
```

you need the engine first, it's the same case as you would call

```
Car car = new Car(new Engine());
```

It will then use the engine object to call constructor in Car class

2)

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
```

You need first to have a Window object in order to call `requestFeature` on it, it's that simple.
The second part it's the same case as above (FEATURE_ACTION_BAR is actually a static int in Window class and it's 8)

You can easily check it by yourself by debugging the instructions and use "step into" (F7)